# Solidity modulo operation on int256 type

Tags: solidity

Why `int256(5) % int256(-2) == int256(1)` but `int256(-5) % int256(2) == int256(-1)`?
I mean `int256(5) % int256(-2) == int256(1)` could also be `int256(-1)` but why is it not the same?

Answer (score 0):

Since Solidity is a language derived from C/C++ it is likely they are using the standard C definition from a starting point.

See this stackoverflow answer for the details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers.

> C99 requires that when `a/b` is representable:
>
> `(a/b) * b + a%b` shall equal `a`